# How to remove scripts with jquery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I know we can remove specific script with plugin or php functions. but i am just wondering if it is possible to remove `<script>` with jquery.

I am trying to remove script `<script src="/wp-content/uploads/wp-embed.min.js"></script>` with jquery contains `wp-embed.min.js` but didn't worked. any idea?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('html').find('script').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src') === 'wp-embed.min.js'
    }).remove();
    console.log("Script removed");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to remove `wp-embed.min.js` objects (functions, variables and more) from the `window` object (DOM), then no. It is not possible.

See the following snippet, where I attempt to remove `lodash.js` by removing its `script` tag.

```js
console.log("Lodash output #1:", _.sortBy([24,2,556,1,4]));

// remove lodash2
$('script').each(function(i, script){
    var $script = $(script);
    if ($script.attr('src') && $script.attr('src').includes('lodash')) {
         $script.remove();
    }
});

// Lodash test
console.log("Lodash output #2:", _.sortBy([24,2,556,1,4]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am trying remove script from DOM

Comment: @Uzair, please elaborate.